# Excel VBA If range.value = something then

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, vba

What I am looking for is this -

If a value in range of cells equals to some value or same value then it should show "Positive" else "Negative. But when I write like below syntax, it throws an error -

```
If range("F3:H5").value = "X" then

Msgbox "Positive result"

else

Msgbox "Negative result"

end if
```

Comment: "It throws an error" is unhelpful. "It throws a Type Mismatch error" gives us something more to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function

```
    Function EvalRange(inRng As Range, inVal As Variant) As Variant

    Dim CntAll, CntMatch As Double

    CntAll = Application.Count(inRng)
    CntMatch = Application.CountIf(inRng, inVal)

    If CntAll = CntMatch Then
        EvalRange = "Positive Result"
        Else: EvalRange = "Negative Result"
    End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Note: I have not added any error/exception handling as the solution is just for illustration. Assuming, user will make necessary changes for that purpose.

Comment: This is not a correct syntax of writing Application functions. i.e. Application.count.

Comment: Try this out to see the result. I purposefully avoided the use of "Worksheetfunction" and used "Application" to use the function. In a nutshell, statement like Application.Count is more stable than Worksheetfunction.Count

Answer (score 2):

It should serve the purpose:

```
Sub string_validation()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("F3:H8")
        If cel.Value = "hassle" Then
            MsgBox "Positive result"
        Else
            MsgBox "Negative result"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like:

```
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each cell In Range("F3:h5").Cells
    if cell.Value = "X" Then
        found = True
    end if
Next

If found = True Then
    Msgbox "Positive result"
else
    Msgbox "Negative result"
End if
```

Comment: thanks, but i have multiple ranges that I cannot run in a loop. is there a way wherein I can directly validate it? without any loops

Comment: I don't think so. This answers the question as it was stated anyway. The For / Next loop is a trivial amount of extra code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
VBA.MsgBox VBA.IIf(Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(F3:H5 = ""X""))"), "Positive result", "Negative result")
```

""X""            double quotes due to two outer quotes

F3:H5 = ""X""    is an array of boolean results F3=X, F4=X etc.

--               negative turns boolean to 0/1; another negative "back" to 1/0

IIf, Evaluate, SUMPRODUCT...    Functions. Sorry, GIYF.

Comment: It would be better if you explain a bit about your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).